# Java: how to parse JSON string param to string and array?

Tags: java, json

I have JSON data like below being passed to request as `string` parameter.

```
[{
"KK_ID":"22","MONTH":"Jan",
"MY_UNIT":
[{"dataid":"7hENRFVhjmbKmMFX","unit":"10.0"},{"dataid":"G7cuqwxmvx8mFUZN","unit":"20.0"}]
}]
```

How can I parse it to get:

```
KK_ID: 22
MONTH: JAN

to 2D array:
[0][0] dataid:7hENRFVhjmbKmMFX [0][1] unit:10.0
[1][0] dataid:G7cuqwxmvx8mFUZN [1][1] unit:20.0
```

Comment: you can try a json parser such [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/blob/master/MANUAL.md) or gson. then continue from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a json array as (**jsonarray**):

```
[{
"KK_ID":"22","MONTH":"Jan",
"MY_UNIT":
[{"dataid":"7hENRFVhjmbKmMFX","unit":"10.0"},{"dataid":"G7cuqwxmvx8mFUZN","unit":"20.0"}]
}]
```

**The code to parse -**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String KK_ID = jsonObject.getString("KK_ID");
String MONTH = jsonObject.getString("MONTH");

JSONArray innerJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("MY_UNIT");

String[][] strAry = new String[innerJsonArray.length()][2];

for (int i = 0; i < innerJsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject innerJsonobject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     strAry[i][0] = innerJsonobject.getString("dataid");
     strAry[i][1] = innerJsonobject.getString("unit");
 }
```

*Hope this help you.*

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/).

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
data = gson.fromJson(mystring, List<MyData>.class);

class MyData {
  int KK_ID;
  String MONTH;
  List<Map<String, String>> MY_UNIT;
}
```